# I can't get Xamarin to debug my android application -- missing android.jar?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, mobile-development

I recently updated my VS 2017 Enterprise which may be an issue but I can't understand why I'm having errors with this.  I have android studio installed and installed the APK using android studio.  Visual studio is pointed towards the apk that I installed using android studio.  But everytime I try to debug my app, whether using a physical device or emulator, I get an error; "Could not find android.jar for API level".  And when  I try in VS2019 enterprise edition, I get a couple errors: "Invalid value 'armeabi' in $(AndroidSupportedAbis). This ABI is no longer supported. "  and also something like "java.exe exited with code 2" or something like that.

I have tried in VS going to Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager  and pointing the SDK location to an empty folder and selecting Android 8.0, 8.1, 9.0 and having it install but after it is done installing its like Visual Studio doesn't find it to be a sufficient APK.  I don't understand.

Also when I navigate to where my APK is located (the one installed by Android Studio) there are 3 'platforms' and each one has an android.jar file.  So not sure why VS cant recognize that.

Also I am always running as Admin.

Comment: Why are you deploying the app via A. Studio, vs. building/deploying via Visual Studio? (i.e. Visual Studio is not going to debug an Android Studio built/deployed app)

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm not depoying via Android STudio, Im only using Android studio to get the Android APK.  I'm building/deploying/debugging using Visual studio. I don't believe i said I was using android studio to run the app

Comment: `...installed the APK using android studio...` ? `...towards the apk that I installed using android studio...` ? Why are you using Android Studio?

Comment: @SushiHangover how else do you install the apk for visual studio without? I thought this was a common way of getting it.  pretty sure I used android studio because i saw someone else online recommend it.

Comment: @SushiHangover Lets say I remove android studio  and delete the apk in the location that Android studio had installed it.  What  should I do then to have a fresh version of the APK for Visual Studio to work with?

Comment: Build and install the app via Visual Studio. This is an Xamarin-based app correct?

Comment: Visual Studio can build and deploy directly to an attached android device or emulator.  Android Studio should not need to involved.  I've built dozens of Android apps with Xamarin and never once used Android Studio.

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes it is a Xamarin app.  It started about a week ago when it started saying it couldn't find the android.jar file.  I have no idea why.

Comment: @SushiHangover I uninstalled android studio and created a new android folder on my hard drive and through visual studio > Tools > Android SDK Manager, then browsed to the new folder and installed android 7.1, 8.0, 8.1, and 9.0.  Just the platform for each.  and under the Tools tab i have sdk tools, sdk platform-tools, emulator and some of the build tools options selected. still having the same error though.

Comment: If you got ` "Invalid value 'armeabi' in $(AndroidSupportedAbis). This ABI is no longer supported. " `, please open your android project propertise,  select the `Android Option`, click the `Advanced`, unselect the `armeabi` like this sceenshot.https://imgur.com/a/ursi4zv